# JS/PHP Base64 image appears black

Tags: php, angularjs, base64, phpmailer

So I have a hybrid mobile app based an AngularJS, and I'm trying to send a Base64 encoded image to a PHP webservice, witch embeds it in an email(with PHPMailer). Only problem is image appears as black square every time. I've tried so many different ways of encoding/decoding it, but nothing works. Here's my code:

JS:

```
   encodeImageUri: function(imageUri)
        {
            var c=document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            var img=new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                c.width=this.width;
                c.height=this.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
            };
            img.src=imageUri;
            var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            return dataURL;
          }
          //send dataURL with $http.post()
```

PHP:

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $imageData = $request->imageData;
        $body = "";
        if($imageData != ""){
           $imageHTML ="<img src=\"".$imageData."\"/>";
           $body = $body.$imageHTML;
        } 
    }
    //send email with $body with PHP mailer..
```

Here's $imageData:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Help please ?

Edit: Turns out the problem was the encoding. I changed the options of the cordova camera to `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` witch requires no encoding. Worked like a a charm.

Comment: can you `var_dump($imageData);` ?

Comment: Hope you realize that embedded images don't work in many email clients

Answer (score 0):

In short, data URIs in email are worth avoiding. PHPMailer has a built-in converter from data URIs into embedded images as part of the `msgHTML` function, so try using that. Alternatively, do the conversion yourself - [PHP has a built-in data converter](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) you can use:

```
$rawimagedata = file_get_contents($imagedata);
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($rawimagedata, 'image1', 'myimage', 'base64', 'image/png');
```

You may find that `msgHtml()` easier as it takes care of naming everything and setting content IDs.

What @charlietfl said is partly true - many clients do not support *data URIs*, but nearly all support embedded images - for many years it was the *only* way that images were supported!